# how to truncate dinamic string in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have dynamic array data which has different code :

```
[0] 18572834-2.2.2.4
[1] 185-2.1
```

here i want to fetch data after ( - )
dynamically, may I know what function to use in php ?

output

```
[0] 2.2.2.4
[1] 2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

`foreach`, `array_map`, `explode` you should know the drill.

```php
$arr = ["18572834-2.2.2.4", "185-2.1"];
$result = array_map(function($item) {
  return explode("-", $item, 2)[1];
}, $arr);
```

Comment: remove the `$` before `explode`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question I think you can first implode the array to get a string and then explode the array using "-" as separator.

```
$arr = implode("", $arr);
$splitted = explode("-", $arr)
```

Then you have an array with "185" at index 0 and "2.1" at index 1 so you just take the index 1.

So:

```
$splitted[0x1] = 2.1
```

But Explode will divide the string in pieces for every delimitator, so if you have:  123-456-789 you will get an array

```
$arr[0] = 123 
$arr[1] = 456 
$arr[2] = 789
```

And I don't know if it is what you want. If you want to take the numbers only from the first delimiter (so 456-789) you can use a regular expression or split and then rejoin the array or do a substring from the position of the delimiter

Comment: You *can* explode ("-", $str, 2)

Comment: true story explode has the limit I forgot about it xD